# How can I check if installed apps are latest versions?

Tags: applications

I used to have an app on my Desire HD that I *think* was called Something Dog. When launched, it would list all the installed apps and whether they were the latest versions.

My Desire HD crashed a while ago, and all my data was lost. I've since bought a One X and I'd like to have this app again.

Does anyone know what it's called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "dog" you are talking about is [aTrackdog](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.aTrackDog). :)

It queries your installed apps and compares them to the latest known versions.

Comment: You are welcome, you can still upvote :)

Comment: At the time I couldn't (not enough rep), done now though ;)

Comment: Is there an alternate link for aTrackdog, as the one above is unavailable on google play.